# What's the status of the land border crossing between Panama/Nicaragua and Costa Rica during the COVID-19 pandemic?

Tags: covid-19, borders, panama, costa-rica, nicaragua

I wonder whether it is possible for a French citizen and US legal permanent resident to cross borders via land between Panama/Nicaragua and Costa Rica during the COVID-19 pandemic. The individual doesn't have any special visa, work permit or residence in any Central American country.

https://reopen.europa.eu/en lists the land/air/sea border status for EU countries only, and https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm only mentions air travel.

The most recent update on the land border crossing is https://thecostaricanews.com/costa-rica-panama-land-border-continues-to-be-blocked-after-almost-two-weeks/ ([mirror](https://archive.vn/f2HQx)), which dates back from
October 17, 2020.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As at late December 2020, Costa Rica does not appear to permit foreign tourists to cross any land border into Costa Rica. From an article [Residents returning to Costa Rica via land borders must isolate, government says](https://ticotimes.net/2020/12/23/residents-returning-to-costa-rica-via-land-borders-must-isolate-government-says):

> The Costa Rican Presidency on Wednesday published a reminder that residents who leave the country and return via land borders will be issued a 14-day isolation order.
>
> **The land borders remain closed to incoming tourists**. Citizens, residents and tourists who enter Costa Rica via a flight are not issued an isolation order.

At the time of this writing, Costa Rica allows foreign tourists to enter *by air* only, with no isolation or quarantine restrictions.